# Can't build QtD on Windows 7

Tags: d

I was trying to build QtD using the instructions here:

http://www.dsource.org/projects/qtd/wiki/BuildWindows

I downloaded the repo. 
Went inside the repo (it was called repo and not qtd as the instructions said).

I created the build_dir dir and went inside there.

I used the:

```
cmake -G"MinGW Makefiles" ../
```

Command and then I got the following error:

```
Error: CMake: Could not create named generator MinGW Makefiles
```

Taking advice from a friend I went inside the d2 directory and went inside the qtd dir there, and repeated the steps above.

Same error.

I have the components the instructions listed, and with what I believe is needed on my PATH

What am I doing wrong? Are there any other instructions I'm missing?

Comment: You might have better luck if you use the `cmake` gui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd heard that QtD was no longer maintained. Certainly, the last commit on dsource was 3 years ago: http://www.dsource.org/projects/qtd/browser

However, [the d wiki](http://wiki.dlang.org/GUI_Libraries) has a [link to bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/qtd/repo) where someone has a version of it which had a commit as recently as December. So, I guess that someone revived it and put it up on bitbucket.

However, regardless of whether the bitbucket repo is now indeed the "official" QtD repo, given that the last commit to the dsource repo was 3 years ago, the odds are very high that it no longer compiles, even if you use the correct build commands. So, I'd advise checking out the bitbucket repo and seeing if you can get that to work rather than trying to get the version on dsource to work. And even if you could get the dsource version to work, it's clearly unmaintained, so you're not going to want to use it long term, whereas the bitbucket version does appear to have had work done on it relatively recently.